# In Python how do you plot a list that has numbers and text in the same list?

Tags: python

I want to plot the below lists.
I am getting an error.  I think it is because of the string in the list with integers.
x and y must have same first dimension

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

success2019 = np.array([20.2,23.1,25.5,28,30.3,30.5,32,34.1,36.1,42.3,51.9])
units2019 = np.array([75,74,'52a',50,30.49,51,37,'37A','30A',58])


plt.plot(success2019, units2019)
plt.show()
```

Comment: you are having string as a value and also the number of elements are not matching which is giving you this error. so these are the two issues.

Comment: Where exactly on the y axis would you want to plot "52a"? At 52?

Comment: Forget Python -- I have no idea how I could plot this by hand. What would a plot even mean here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the error is not because of string in the list. The shape of the lists is not the same. Try using len() for both lists and equal the number of elements.

Try using this code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

success2019 = np.array([20.2,23.1,25.5,28,30.3,30.5,32,34.1,36.1,42.3,51.9])
units2019 = np.array([75,74,'52a',50,30.49,51,37,'37A','30A',58,11]) # adding 11 to make them of same shape

print(len(success2019),len(units2019))
plt.plot(success2019, units2019)
plt.show()
```

Edit:

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

THE CODE WORKS WITHOUT ANY ERROR

Comment: Lets assume the lengths are the same. On which axis (x or y) would you plot 52a, 37a, 30a. There is already 30 and 37.